# Is is possible to fake a AES encrypted data?

Tags: encryption, cryptography, aes

Given a AES secret key, is it possible to fake a data that can be decrypt using that key? the decrypted data doesn't need to be meaningful, just want to know if can fake a encrypted data.

Comment: Yes.  AES in general provides no integrity checking and there aren't many ways to determining if a given encrypted data is gibberish, other than hints such as (padded) length.  http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/9437/does-symmetric-encryption-provide-data-integrity

Comment: You'll really need to define "fake" in context.  Any multiple of 16 bytes can look like AES-encrypted data.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not directly related to programming. This question is much better suited for [crypto.se] or [security.se].

Comment: depends; AEG-GCM is authenticated, but not all modes are.

Answer (score 1):

AES is a symmetrical cipher, i.e. the same key is used to both encrypt and decrypt data. As such, the key must be known to both ends of communication, and no one else. Authentication and key-exchange is done via public-key protocols, such as [Diffie-Hellman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) key exchange.

Given these, if you are the third person to possess an AES key, I assume that you cannot send "fake data" to the recipient, as authentication will fail (no negotiation has taken place). If you have established such a connection, you can send whatever you want (you can encrypt gibberish and send it). If you mean to alter an encrypted packet, you can do it without decrypting it and re-encrypting it, but it's most likely to fail integrity tests (e.g. if hashes or CRC are present).